# grep a value from a file then use it as a folder name to locate a file and plot

Tags: gnuplot

Sorry for the confusing title. I couldn't find a better title to describe the issue. I am using gnuplot to plot some files. The files that I am trying to plot are locate in a folder titled process. Inside the process folder is another folder named 100; the structure is as below;

"plot" is the file I recall using gnuplot.

The file plot has the following line;

```
file='file.dat'
time = "cat file | grep 'time' | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d ';' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'"

plot \
      "process/".time."/speed.txt" using 1:3 with line lt 2 lc 6 title ""
```

So, the goal is to look for the word time in the file.dat and cut its value, which in this case is 100, and use it as a folder name where I am trying to plot the speed.txt file. However, what I have doesn't seem to work when I execute gnuplot. Anyone can help please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How does the file `file.dat` look like? How are `time` and `100` arranged/connected? By space or `=` or something else inbetween? Can you give an example? I'm not familiar with `cat, grep, cut, tr, awk`, but I assume you could also do it with gnuplot alone.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! The file.dat has a line time:100. So, I used grep and awk to get only the value 100 to be used as a folder name. I hope this clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to run a shell command from gnuplot and get its standard output as text, use the `system` function.

```
filter_command = "cat ..." 
time = system( filter_command )
```

Secondly, the command string "cat ..." which you have defined will not work properly if you just pass it to `system`. You intend for the string `file` in the `cat file` to be expanded as `cat file.dat` from gnuplot's `file` variable.
To do that, we need one more step. There are two ways to do that.

1. Concatnating strings using `.` operator

```
file='file.dat'
filter_command = "cat " . file . " | grep 'time' | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d ';' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'"
```

2. Using `sprintf` function

```
file='file.dat'
filter_template = "cat %s | grep 'time' | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d ';' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'" 
filter_command  = sprintf(filter_template, file)
```

### Script

The final script looks like this.

```
file='file.dat'
filter_template = "cat %s | grep 'time' | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d ';' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'" 
filter_command  = sprintf(filter_template, file)

time = system( filter_command )

plot "process/".time."/speed.txt" using 1:3 with line lt 2 lc 6 title ""
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Although gnuplot is not made for parsing files, you nevertheless can do it, sometimes with strange workarounds.
There is certainly a way to do it with the tools you mentioned: cat, grep, cut, tr and awk. However, not everybody is using Linux and has these tools at hand. Hence, if possible and although it's not optimal, I personally prefer to have "gnuplot-only" solutions which are platform-independent.

So, what the code below basically does is to "plot" the file `file.dat` into a dummy table line by line and everytime checking if the current line contains the string `time:`. If yes, write the rest of the line into the variabe `myValue`.

Get more information on the commands: `help strstrt`, `help strlen`, `help strcol`, `help ternary`, `help datafile separator`.

**File:** `file.dat`

```
### file.dat
This is a data file
which contains something
but also a line with
time:100
And many more things...
Maybe also some data...?
1  1.1
2  2.2
3  3.3
4  4.4
# end of file
```

**Code:**

```
### extract key&value from a file and use it in path
reset session

myFile = 'file.dat'
myKey = 'time:'
myValue = ''
myPath(s) = sprintf('process/%s/speed.txt',s)
getValue(line) = strstrt(line,myKey) > 0 ? myValue = line[strstrt(line,myKey)+strlen(myKey):] : myValue

# extract the value for key
set datafile separator "\n"
set table $Dummy
    plot myFile u (getValue(strcol(1))) w table
unset table
set datafile separator whitespace

print myValue
print myPath(myValue)

# Your plot command would then look, e.g. like this:
plot myPath(myValue) using 1:3 with line lt 2 lc 6 title ""

### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
100
process/100/speed.txt
```

Comment: That looks promising with the exception if I have the header time in the file.dat in this format; time 100; instead of time:100

Comment: that's why I asked above and you wrote in the comments "The file.dat has a line `time:100`."  Well, then simply replace the line to: `myKey = 'time '`. binzo's solution is the solution for Linux users with awk installed. My cumbersome gnuplot-only solution should work for everybody.

Comment: Theozh your solution is great, and it makes sense! stackoverflow didn't allow me to accept both solutions. But, again your script is perfect too.